# Django Celery Periodic task is not running on mentioned crontab

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using the below packages.

```
celery==5.1.2
Django==3.1
```

I have 2 periodic celery tasks, in which I want the first task to run every 15 mins and the second to run every 20 mins. But the problem is that the first task is running on time, while the second is not running.

Although I'm getting a message on console:

```
Scheduler: Sending due task <task_name> (<task_name>)
```

But the logs inside that function are not coming on the console.

Please find the following files,

celery.py

```py
from celery import Celery, Task
app = Celery('settings')
...

class PeriodicTask(Task):
    @classmethod
    def on_bound(cls, app):
        app.conf.beat_schedule[cls.name] = {
            "schedule": cls.run_every,
            "task": cls.name,
            "args": cls.args if hasattr(cls, "args") else (),
            "kwargs": cls.kwargs if hasattr(cls, "kwargs") else {},
            "options": cls.options if hasattr(cls, "options") else {}
        }
```

tasks.py

```py
from celery.schedules import crontab
from settings.celery import app, PeriodicTask
...

@app.task(
    base=PeriodicTask,
    run_every=crontab(minute='*/15'),
    name='task1',
    options={'queue': 'queue_name'}
)
def task1():
    logger.info("task1 called")

@app.task(
    base=PeriodicTask,
    run_every=crontab(minute='*/20'),
    name='task2'
)
def task2():
    logger.info("task2 called")
```

Please help me to find the bug here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled logging in celery. The docs says that for logging you have to enable logging. Here is the link for the docs [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.1.2/userguide/tasks.html) refer to logging section.

Comment: Hello. I think I was also doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled logging. Actually, both tasks are using same logger instance so, logging is not the issue here.